# Android - Switching to activity from status bar

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications, alarmmanager

First of all, I know this question has been asked and answered many times. I would not be reposting if any of those solutions had worked for me.

I have a 10 activities that I create and switch to before I get to the activity that
starts the alarm.

Then I create the alarmManager from within the last activity(that the user interacts with) with the following code:

```
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
            @Override
            //Code adapted from example at android-er.blogspot.com
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Declare the intent to start a new service
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Page10.this, AlarmService.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Page10.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                //Create the alarm manager and connect it to ALARM_SERVICE
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                //Use the calendar to time the action of the alarm
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

                //Set the alarm to buzz after the time defined in calendar
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(Page10.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Start the main activity, the alarm service is now running in the background
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
```

After creating the alarm I switch to the main activity, as I want the alarm to run in the background. The pendingIntent passed to the alarmManager is the following service:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //Get a notification manager
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager SlugNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        //Instantiate the notification
        int icon = R.drawable.slugmoodtextless;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Survey Ready";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        //Set notification messages and PendingIntent
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Slugmood";
        CharSequence contentText = "Survey Ready!";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        //Pass notification to notification manager
        final int HELLO_ID = 1;
        SlugNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I did not include the other overridden methods, for brevity and since they are not used by my service. So what I want my service to do is send a notification to the status bar when the alarm goes off, then the user can click on the notification to be returned to page1 (the second activity that gets created). Everything works up until the user clicks the notification. Then the program crashes with a nondescriptive "program crashed unexpectedly" and returns me to the page before page10(not page1, where I set the pendingIntent).

Now, I had initially just wanted the service to start the page1 activity immediately. Using the notification system was my solution to the exact same crash occurring when I simply started the page1 activity from the service.

Solutions I have tried:
  -Set all sorts of flags on the intent, including CLEAR_TASK, CLEAR_TOP, REORDER_ACTIVITY, etc
  -Tried being sure to finish() all activities before I try to restart them from the activity
  -Tried putting the code to send the notification in various locations in the service (onCreate, onStart etc)
  -Tried resuming activities rather than restarting them.
  -As well as pretty much everything else mentioned on StackOverflow about starting activities from services, using the status bar, etc.

So I'm stumped. If anyone knows how to handle this, I would really appreciate the help.

Edit: Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
11-01 04:58:21.111: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
11-01 04:58:28.332: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
11-01 04:58:29.412: ERROR/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
11-01 04:58:29.412: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-01 04:58:29.412: ERROR/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
11-01 04:58:29.431: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
11-01 04:58:35.131: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
11-01 04:58:35.131: ERROR/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58): Failure starting core service
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
11-01 04:58:35.382: ERROR/System(58):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
11-01 04:58:36.081: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-01 04:58:36.081: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-01 04:58:36.081: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-01 04:58:36.091: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-01 04:58:36.091: ERROR/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-01 04:58:37.572: ERROR/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
11-01 04:58:38.641: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-01 04:58:38.691: ERROR/logwrapper(148): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-01 04:58:38.702: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
11-01 04:58:46.651: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.scrumptious.slugmood/org.scrumptious.slugmood.Page1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at org.scrumptious.slugmood.Page1.onCreate(Page1.java:36)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-01 05:00:22.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     ... 11 more
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.scrumptious.slugmood/org.scrumptious.slugmood.Page1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at org.scrumptious.slugmood.Page1.onCreate(Page1.java:36)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-01 05:05:15.972: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(286):     ... 11 more
```

I'm still not entirely sure what my problem is, though it seems to be that Android is unable to find page1.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "program crashed unexpectedly" message.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NullPointerException` in `onCreate()` of `org.scrumptious.slugmood.Page1`, in the `Page1.java` source file, line 36.